# force sync with iCloud through a button

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

My app uses iCloud to sync. In my main view controller's viewWillAppear:

```
// Configure persistant store on iCloud

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TodayViewController.persistentStoreDidChange), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TodayViewController.persistentStoreWillChange(_:)), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TodayViewController.recieveICloudChanges(_:)), name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```

and viewWillDisappear:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
}
```

However, sometimes this takes too slow to sync. I would like the users to force sync by tapping a button, or maybe by swiping down the tableView to refresh (resync). How do I do that?

@IBAction forceSyncButton() {

** what to put in here?**

}

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using Core Data's built-in iCloud support. Unfortunately there is no public API to force a sync to occur. It's handled automatically, and your app cannot do anything to change the schedule.

Comment: You probably want to move away from iCloud Core Data anyway. In the updated iOS 10 docs, pretty much everything with it is deprecated. Maybe look at ensembles.io

Comment: Oh alright, I'll take note. iCloud Core Data seems really frustrating and slow to work with too. Thanks for the advice! I'm new at this.

Comment: @TomHarrington, is this still valid ?

Comment: The API from this question has been deprecated and is no longer available. There's a new CloudKit-based version, and I believe it's the same situation-- syncing is automatic, not initiated by the app. However it seems to work much better, so it shouldn't be a problem.